# .htaccess: RewriteRule pattern-matching

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite for rewriting my links as follows. I defined a redirect from `/test/1234_5678_...` to `/test.php?id=1234` as follows:

```
RewriteRule test/(.*)_(.*)$ test.php?id=$1
```

It works perfectely. Now I wanted to add the following redirect: `/test/1234_5678_.../print` to `/test.php?id=1234&print`. Therefore I added the following line before the one above. The redirect is not working and it seems as if only the second rule applies. Am I doing anything wrong with the pattern matching? Is it a problem that there can be more than one underscore and I only used one in the pattern?

```
RewriteRule test/(.*)_(.*)/print$ test.php?id=$1&print
RewriteRule test/(.*)_(.*)$ test.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both rules work fine for me, but you probably want to change the first grouping to `([0-9]+)` or `([^_]+)`, and the second group to `[^/]+`, and add some `L` flags:

```
RewriteRule test/([^_]+)_([^/]+)/print$ test.php?id=$1&print [L]
RewriteRule test/([^_]+)_([^/]+)$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That's weired. It's not working for me. I'll double-check and try to provide an example if I can't fix it.