# Match url with no folders in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to 301 redirect  `www.example.com/sample-page-1`  to  `www.example.com/en/sample-page-1` and the http requirement served from file `sample-page-1.php`

This rules works ok:

```
RewriteRule ^sample-page-1$ https://www.example.com/en/sample-page-1 [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en/sample-page-1$ sample-page-1.php
```

However, how can I have one set of rules to match any page such as `sample-page-2` , `corporate-info` , `customer-service` , etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess: RewriteRule pattern-matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625484/htaccess-rewriterule-pattern-matching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have rules as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /en/$1 [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^en/([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
```